# API call returns service is temporarily unavailable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to get a report from MOZ API to work. Unfortunately this is the response I'm getting:

```
{
  "status" : "503",
  "error_message" : "Service Temporarily Unavailable"
}
```

This is my code:

```
function MozCall(callback) {
  var mozCall = '';

  // Set your expires times for several minutes into the future.
  // An expires time excessively far in the future will not be honored by the Mozscape API.
  // Divide the result of Date.now() by 1000 to make sure your result is in seconds.
  var expires = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 300;
  var accessId = 'mozscape-b3978adbec';
  var secretKey = '5f95cb81c5f121904d012488e28e05e';

  // `bitFlagExampleValues` is a list of bitFlag values as strings that we'll
  // loop over and sum together using helper function: `sumColumnValues`
  var bitFlagExampleValues = [
    '144115188075855872',
    '68719476736',
    '34359738368',
  ];
  var sumColumnValues = function(bitFlagValues) {
    return bitFlagValues.reduce(function(accu, bitFlag) {
      var accuValBig = new bigJs(accu);
      var bitFlagBig = new bigJs(bitFlag);
      var bigSum = accuValBig.plus(bitFlagBig);

      return bigSum.toString();
    }, 0);
  };

  // 'cols' is the sum of the bit flags representing each field you want returned.
  // Learn more here: https://moz.com/help/guides/moz-api/mozscape/api-reference/url-metrics
  // returns "144115291155070976"
  var cols = sumColumnValues(bitFlagExampleValues);

  // Put each parameter on a new line.
  var stringToSign = accessId + '\n' + expires;

  //create the hmac hash and Base64-encode it.
  var signature = crypto
    .createHmac('sha1', secretKey)
    .update(stringToSign)
    .digest('base64');
  //URL-encode the result of the above.
  signature = encodeURIComponent(signature);

  var postData = JSON.stringify(['www.moz.com']);

  var options = {
    hostname: 'lsapi.seomoz.com',
    path: '/linkscape/url-metrics/?Cols=' +
      cols +
      '&AccessID=' +
      accessId +
      '&Expires=' +
      expires +
      '&Signature=' +
      signature,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': postData.length,
    },
  };

  var responseData = '';

  var req = http.request(options, function(response) {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
      responseData += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
      console.log(responseData);
    });
  });
  req.end();
}
// if (req.user.isPremium == false) {
let freeReportCalls = [MozCall];
// Free user - Single report
// let website = req.body.website0;
async.parallel(freeReportCalls, function(err, results) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(results);
    res.render('reports/report', {
      title: 'Report',
      // bw: JSON.parse(results[0]),
      // ps: JSON.parse(results[0]),
      // bw: results[1],
      // al: results[2],
      // moz: results[2],
      user: req.user,
    });
  }
});
```

I'm using basically an example code from the moz docs (found here: https://github.com/seomoz/SEOmozAPISamples/blob/master/javascript/node/batching-urls-sample.js). I'm not sure what the issue is. I waited since yesterday but the problem persists so it's not temporary.

Edit: Breaking the API key results in a different issue, so I'm guessing it's connecting to Moz servers.

Comment: Usually that happens when you stop an application pool in IIS. So that might be an issue on their side. Maybe the request you're trying to make has been moved to a different url?

Comment: What do you mean by 'stop an application pool in IIS'?

Comment: IIS is where sites and services are hosted on windows servers. An application pool for a site must be running in for the site to be live or a service to be available. So stopping the pool gives that error

Comment: Yhm. But wouldn't using the wrong url return 404?

Comment: In a nutshell, 404 means site is up but page/request not found. 503 means site is down and not available

Comment: Hm. Ok. So you're suggesting to make sure the API url is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the example code didn't work for me. Instead of passing options I just passed the whole url and this worked. Like this:

```
var postData = JSON.stringify([website, 'www.google.com']);
console.log(postData);

var options = {
  hostname: 'lsapi.seomoz.com',
  path: '/linkscape/url-metrics/' + postData + '?Cols=' +
    '4' + '&AccessID=' + accessId +
    '&Expires=' + expires + '&Signature=' + signature,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': postData.length
  }
};

var responseData = "";

// 'http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/google.com?Cols=4&AccessID='+accessId+'&Expires='+expires+'&Signature='+signature
var req = http.get(`http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/${website}?Cols=${cols}&AccessID=${accessId}&Expires=${expires}&Signature=${signature}`,function(response) {
  response.setEncoding('utf8');
  response.on('data', function(chunk) {
    responseData += chunk;
  });
  response.on('end', function() {
    console.log(responseData);
  });
});
req.end();
```

`Website` is a variable passed to the router through a view.